# Computer boots into GRUB after installing Ubunutu 20.04 as dual boot option

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

Exactly as the title says.  I can type exit and it continues to the boot options and load windows or linux as usual.  I tried updating my graphics drivers as I saw that was a solution to a similar issue on another question.  But it didnt work.

It's not a big deal, but would prefer to boot to boot options first.  Any ideas?

Comment: What brand/model system?What video card/chip. Just to confirm boot settings: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I appreciate the response, but could you clarify exactly how to do these things you asked.  I am relatively inexperienced with linux

Comment: Please follow link to Boot-Repair and use the instructions to add ppa and download & run Boot-Repair. Do not run any suggested repairs, just click on the summary report. do not post full `sudo lshw -short`, but it can tell you hardware details of your system. See also `man lshw` to learn about it.